# Most efficient way to delete old files using bash

Tags: bash, unix, find

I am currently executing this command every 30 min via  a bash script(on Centos 6) to delete files that are around 1 hr old.The problem is that the `find` command is using 45% of my cpu at all times.Is there a way to optimise it.There is about 200k Items in cache at any point in time

```
find /dev/shm/cache -type f -mmin +59 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to run the process as lower priority using `nice`:

```
nice -n 19 find ...
```

Another thing, it might not make a difference in performance,
but to delete matching files with `find`,
a simpler way is `-delete` instead of `-exec`:

```
find /dev/shm/cache -type f -mmin +59 -delete
```

... that is if your version of `find` supports it (thanks [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for pointing out) (and modern versions do...)

Comment: Not all implementations of `find` support `-delete`, but it's very good to use if available.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is starting a new invocation of `rm` for each file that's found, which can be very expensive. You can use an alternate syntax that sends multiple arguments to `rm`, in batches as large as the OS allows. This is done by ending the command with `+` instead of `;`

```
find /dev/shm/cache -type f -mmin +59 -exec rm -f {} +
```

You can also use the `-delete` option, as in janos's answer; it should be even more efficient because it doesn't have to run an external process at all. I'm showing this answer because it generalizes to other commands as well, which may not have equivalent options, e.g.

```
-exec grep foo {} +
```